# List Parents of Children having certain values

Tags: custom-fields, search

Is there a way to query the Custom Fields on a Child and then show their Parent's detials? Scenario: email all parents whose children attend a certain class.

Comment: Are you using relationships to connect Parents to their children? First thoughts here would be to use smart groups for each class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, using Advanced Search (**Search menu » Advanced Search**).  Set up the search the same way you would in order to find the children.  Additionally, set the "Display Results As" at the top to "Related Contacts", and select the "Parent of" relationship.

[image: Advanced Search - display results as]

Answer (score 0):

You can explore [Extended Reports](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) extension that allows extend related Relationship Reports with details of both parts of the relationship.

Comment: Can You use Extended Report to send mails or mailings ?

Comment: No. I think Extended Reports have the same actions as core Reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a list (i.e. not to send mails), and are based upon Drupal, you can also use Drupal Views (> advanced > Relationships).